# Selenium Select Object selectByIndex method examines index attribute instead of counting. Why?

Tags: java, select, selenium

Disclaimer: I'm new to StackOverflow, at least in terms of asking my own questions, so if there's anything wrong or 'bad practice' about this one please give me some pointers.

Recently at work I've had cause to use Selenium and, being new to the tool, there have been a few times when I've wound up scratching my head over why something is done a certain way. Usually the reason becomes apparent later, but not in this case.

Currently I'm writing some browser automation which involves indexing search combinations and noting how many results appear for that combination on various sites related to the company I'm working for.

For most of these sites, the searches will usually be defined via keywords and drop-down menus which I'm handling via Selenium's Select object. Specifically I've been using the selectByIndex method to iterate through the various combinations.

One thing that I noticed was that, using this method, the further down the list of options I got the longer the method took. When I opened up the declaration the code I found was as follows:

```
  /**
   * Select the option at the given index. This is done by examing the "index" attribute of an
   * element, and not merely by counting.
   * 
   * @param index The option at this index will be selected
   */
  public void selectByIndex(int index) {
    String match = String.valueOf(index);

    boolean matched = false;
    for (WebElement option : getOptions()) {
      if (match.equals(option.getAttribute("index"))) {
        setSelected(option);
        if (!isMultiple()) {
          return;
        }
        matched = true;
      }
    }
    if (!matched) {
      throw new NoSuchElementException("Cannot locate option with index: " + index);
    }
  }
```

What I'm confused about is why this code is written so that it examines the 'index' attribute. As far as I can tell the getOptions() method returns a list of the options available to the selector based on tag so it should be accurate, and considering that I've been listing the indexed search combinations using the same method and those have been accurate I'm fairly sure it is.

So, right now I've extended the class and overloaded the method to just direct it straight to the corresponding index as I do have a non-trivial number of search combinations to check and any increase in speed is valuable. There don't appear to be any issues cropping up with the overloaded code and everything seems to be accurate so I'm wondering why this method is written in this way? Could anyone enlighten me?

Comment: Don't worry about your *Disclaimer*; your question is perfectly fine! Also, interesting. I do not know the answer, but you might be better off asking in https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/selenium-developers

Comment: Can you run your overloaded code with Nested options and see if it working fine. Use [link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_optgroup)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Select the option at the given index. This is done by examing the "index" attribute of an element, and not merely by counting.

I believe this is done to overcome the possibility of [Nested Options](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.6) or OPTGROUP in the Select Dropdown tag. Consider the below Select tag:

```
<SELECT name="ComOS">
  <OPTION selected label="none" value="none">None</OPTION>
  <OPTGROUP label="PortMaster 3">
    <OPTION label="3.7.1" value="pm3_3.7.1">PortMaster 3 with ComOS 3.7.1</OPTION>
    <OPTION label="3.7" value="pm3_3.7">PortMaster 3 with ComOS 3.7</OPTION>
    <OPTION label="3.5" value="pm3_3.5">PortMaster 3 with ComOS 3.5</OPTION>
  </OPTGROUP>
  <OPTGROUP label="PortMaster 2">
    <OPTION label="3.7" value="pm2_3.7">PortMaster 2 with ComOS 3.7</OPTION>
    <OPTION label="3.5" value="pm2_3.5">PortMaster 2 with ComOS 3.5</OPTION>
  </OPTGROUP>
  <OPTGROUP label="IRX">
    <OPTION label="3.7R" value="IRX_3.7R">IRX with ComOS 3.7R</OPTION>
    <OPTION label="3.5R" value="IRX_3.5R">IRX with ComOS 3.5R</OPTION>
  </OPTGROUP>
</SELECT>
```

In this Select tag, merely counting the index and find the element is not enough as it may return multiple indexes and give error/exceptions.

Moreover, if multiple option tags are found it should be notified also. Hence, 'probably' this may be the reason for examining the "index" attribute before actually returning the element.

In your case, it is better to overload the method and go by indexes as selectByIndex is bound to get slow for huge amount of options tags.

Edit:

Editing after reading the comments. The statement `for (WebElement option : getOptions())` is actually slowing the code(Question mostly focus on increasing the speed). So, it really do not matter if the solutions is done by examining the index attribute or other way as that is not the reason for slow speed.

Also, examining the index attribute is helpful for nested options as it indexes the options as the child of Select, and not only as immediate child of Select.

Comment: Have you tested it.Are you sure I tried this and it is working fine by the method that op asked

Comment: @Madhan What have you tried that is working fine? Op asked about why the method may have been written this way

Comment: *find the element is not enough as it may return multiple indexes and give error/exceptions.* how do you say so

Comment: What is that you are unable to understand? What do understand by Index?

Comment: The thing is directly working with indexes in the above code may not be able to give the accurate result. Sometimes it may give more than one element and some time element not found exception.

Comment: @Manu Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. I have today off work as a holiday, but even without running the code this makes sense for why the method would be written in that way.

Comment: @Madhan I think you might have misunderstood Manu's answer. I overloaded the method written above to just go directly to a specified index because the method in the Selenium Select class was written in a way that slowed down for large numbers of options. I was asking why the code would have been written that way. Manu's answer pointed out what may likely have been the reason for this.

Comment: @Manu How come you are sure that *it may give more than one element and some time element not found exception.*

Comment: @ReidPalmquist that's just his speculation but not the real reason/cause.That's what i'm asking? Whether it's option group or option the `for (WebElement option : getOptions())` will return only the options present inside a select .And your question is why they're checking the index attribute and for that no answer is mentioned here

Comment: @Madhan I feel that it does give a good reason for that though. getOptions returns a list of web elements, but those web elements may have a list position that does not correspond to the index attribute based on nesting. Its a plausible reason for why this method may have been written this way. Frankly I think the fault is mine in that my question may be overly broad, I was mostly seeking to satisfy my curiosity and this answer does.

Comment: @Madhan You are analyzing the answer from inappropriate point. Op asked why it is not done using counting the index? A: Because it may not always find the expected element. And why did Op asked this question? A: Yes, the reason is `for (WebElement option : getOptions())` is making the code slow. So, even if they don't use index attribute as such, Op makes sense as `getOptions()` is the real reason of slow tests.

Comment: @ReidPalmquist Thanks for accepting the answer. Actually, Why the index attribute is chosen, only the code contribute can answer that(really, there may be multiple reasons for this and other alternative solutions that they may have thought of). But, I answered taking the case why directly taking index and finding the element is not implemented.